# Normal distributions and log transformations

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Lets assume I have a origin distribution, lets call it **Omega**, which is heavily skewed and does not seem to be normally distributed.

I now apply a **log(n+1)** function to it and get a normal distribution with little to no skew, lets call it **Beta**.

My question is:
When I calculate confidence intervals for Beta, can I say something like "**Point number 312 in Beta** lies within the 95% confidence interval, so it can be said that **point 312 in Omega** also lies within a 95% confidence interval!"?

Can I assume Omega is normally distributed, because a transformation of the distribution is?

If I can not make those assumptions, which assumptions can be made about Omega which show in Beta and its confidence intervals?

Sorry probably these are very basic questions, but I often fail to grasp the meaning of very mathematical topics which are often described in a very formal way.

Best regards

Comment: The answers to your questions could be "maybe", "no" and "$\log(n+1)$ and its inverse $\exp(y)-1$ are monotonic strictly increasing functions"